# Фильтрация словаря без значений None

Tags: python, dict

Нужно создать словарь `dict3`, который будет в себе содержать все пары (в том числе `None`) `dict2`, но не те `None`, что выходят из `dict1`:

```
dict1 = {'email' : 'abcd@gmail.com',
     'name' : 'Michael',
     'surname' : 'Stans'}


dict2 = {'login' : dict1.get('email'),
     'name' : dict1.get('name'),
     'surname' : dict1.get('surname'),
     'number' : dict1.get('number'),      #  (None)- не нужен
     'age': dict1.get('age'),             #  (None)- не нужен
     'salary' : None,                   # (None)- нужен
     'weight': None}                    # (None)- нужен


dict3 = {?}
```

Comment: Нужен список всех вещей из dict1 которые вы вставляете в dict2 (`['email', 'name', 'surname', 'number', 'age']`) иначе невозможно отличить разные виды None

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если только так

```
dict1 = {'email' : 'abcd@gmail.com',
         'name' : 'Michael',
         'surname' : 'Stans'}

dict2 = {'login' : dict1.get('email'),
     'name' : dict1.get('name'),
     'surname' : dict1.get('surname'),
     'number' : dict1.get('number'),      #  (None)- не нужен
     'age': dict1.get('age'),             #  (None)- не нужен
     'salary' : None,                   # (None)- нужен
     'weight': None}                    # (None)- нужен

values_got_from_dict1 = ['login', 'name', 'surname', 'number', 'age']
dict3 = { k:v for k,v in dict2.items() if v or (not v and k not in values_got_from_dict1)}
print(dict3)
```